# Remove rows for var2 = x where var1=0 and row below has var1=1

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df<-data.frame(client_id = c(7, 7, 7, 17, 17, 17, 19, 
               19, 19,19,19), delivery = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1), order_id = c("snshw","nsnsjjw","smssjjw","jsnn","ksksues","ncbf","nsngw","manhsm","opltkg","snsjue","msmssje"), which_order = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2,
```

And I need to remove rows for each client_id where delivery=0 and a row below has delivery = 1. The dataset after such an operation would look like this:

```
  df<- data.frame(client_id = c(7, 7, 17, 17, 
                     19, 19,19,19), delivery = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1), order_id = c("snshw","smssjjw","jsnn","ncbf","nsngw","opltkg","snsjue","msmssje"), which_order = c(1, 3, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                      3, 1,3,4,5))
```

Do you have any idea what might work? I've tried some dplyr functions but didn't come up with anything useful.

Probably there is no need to solve this for each client_id as there is very low probability that the first row for any client_id has delivery=1 (and therefore low risk that we would delete some rows with higher client_id).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `lead()` to access the next delivery value (use `lag()` if you want to access the previous one) and use `filter()` to select only rows that match your query

Try something like:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- 
  tibble(
    client_id = c(7, 7, 7, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19,19,19), 
    delivery = c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1), 
    order_id = c("snshw","nsnsjjw","smssjjw","jsnn","ksksues","ncbf","nsngw","manhsm","opltkg","snsjue","msmssje"), 
    which_order = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,4,5)
  )

df %>%
  filter(
    !(delivery == 0 & lead(delivery) == 1)
  )
```

This will give:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
  client_id delivery order_id which_order
      <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
1         7        0 snshw              1
2         7        1 smssjjw            3
3        17        0 jsnn               1
4        17        1 ncbf               3
5        19        0 nsngw              1
6        19        1 opltkg             3
7        19        1 snsjue             4
8        19        1 msmssje            5
```